# Allow C# to accept and deal with POST requests

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, json

I've recently been writing a custom API in C# for a ASP.NET project, my question is, how can I implement   a piece of code that allows me to take POST requests and then be a ble to create a SQL query then insert it into the database. (I can use JS if needed)

Pastebin Link: http://pastebin.com/mMN4cZwd

Also I know my code is vulnerable to SQL injections at the moment but don't worry yourself!

Comment: Have you thought about using a web framework (like ASP.NET Web API)? Doing so makes things like accepting and processing POST requests almost trivially easy.

Comment: "Also I know my code is vulnerable to SQL injections at the moment but don't worry yourself!" > We don't, you should...

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'm looking for constructive feedback and help...Stop wasting peoples time.

Comment: @JamesGarner I think all Patrick is trying to do is get you to think about security from the start; he may be concerned you're going to bolt it on afterwards. Obviously he's interested in the question itself as well, otherwise he wouldn't have read it.

Comment: @JamesGarner: I have seen to many software projects (as CTO currently) gone bad, because they said 'we will deal with it later'. **It never happens!!!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Handler( receivepost.ashx) and then :

```
public class receivepost : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {


        if (context.Request.Form["order_id"] != null)
        {

            int orderID = Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["order_id"]);

            // SQL SYNTAX TO SAVE ORDERID IN TO DATABASE
        }

    }



    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Your handler will be called from outside like : www.yourdomain.com/tools/receivepost.ashx